# how to test laravel job on failure

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

i want test my laravel job on failure.
i use laravel 9 and latest phpunit version.

> i think in job mocking exceptions will not be catching.

for example i have a job that in `handle()` functions it's calling an api. i want test that situation the api not work and throw an exception. so in this case `failed()` function called. but in tests, if i mock api http request, if it failed, mock not detect that and test continue. so i can not test `failed()` function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve
this question.  Then, come back and [edit] your question to include a [mre] to
it which helps with troubleshooting.  Good questions tend to receive faster,
better answers from the community.

Comment: Can't you point your test to an invalid URL? this should trigger the failed call, right?

Comment: @blurfus I think he is mocking the HTTP request (you can do so using [`Http::fake`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#faking-responses)) and failing it just using `4xx` or `5xx`

Comment: @blurfus i did, but failed() function not called in job and test continue!

Comment: @matiaslauriti i did, but failed() function not called in job and test continue!

Comment: @FarshidRezaei share your code please, so we can see what you have done as it should be working (share test and real code)

Answer (score 1):

If you use laravel version 7.x or upper, you can use The HTTP facade's fake method to simulate the response that you want and you can get fail action in your job.

for more information, you can [read about that in the laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#faking-specific-urls):

Comment: i did, but failed() function not called in job and test continue!